# Is it good idea to use BootFaces & PrimeFAces together?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Can I use BootFaces and PrimeFaces together?
All I want is bootstrap UI with PrimeFaces Functionality.

How tuff is it to use bootstrap CSS with PrimeFaces components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to add BootFaces to my Primefaces project with about 5 different pages/templates and make it responsive in about 16 hours.

You will need to disable the primefaces theme and manualy import the latest bootstrap or switch to the Primefaces Bootstrap Theme and use the build in (old) Bootstrap version.

BootsFaces supports Primefaces and the BootsFaces page is using PrimeFaces.
I had no problems using components from both framworks together.

Comment: But then if you are using BootFaces, can you use PrimeFaces UI components if you are using BootFaces ? If yes will prime faces UI Component have bootstrap UI ?

Comment: Are you talking about PrimeUI (Javascript Components) ? If you mean PrimeFaces components, i am using them inside of BootFaces tags.

Comment: Yes i was talking about PrimeFaces UI component. Thanks ur info was very helpful, is there any good link from where i can read about BootFaces components etc ?

Comment: You can find all examples on the BootFaces homepage.

Comment: How have you used nested data tables ? It is not available in BootFaces but it is available in PrimeFaces. BootFaces provide very basic data tables. and that is also they are saying experimental.

Comment: If you have completely disabled the primefaces theme, you will need to provide some css for the primefaces components, or use the included primefaces bootstrap theme. Also check this how to make the default datatable responsive: http://blog.sixthpoint.com/bootstrap-3-primefaces-5-datatable-styling/